# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x)(1+x^2)\cdots(1+x^{2n}),|x|<1$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

I get that the limit is

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x)=1$$
because
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+x^{2n})=1,\,\,\lvert x\rvert<1.$$

Is this right?

Comment: You can't use arithmetic of limits, as you're apparently doing,  when the number of factor depends on $\;n\;$ itself.

Comment: Is this $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)...(1+x^{2n})$ or $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)...(1+x^{2^{n}})$?

Comment: @Mike  It is $x^{2n}$

Comment: @displayerror Then the limit is quite intricate. For the product where the general factor is $1+x^{2^k}$, there is a nice explicit limit. If the general factor is $1+x^k$, the limit is not particularly nice, and not easy to find. And why would then the last factor be $1+x^{2n}$ rather than $1+x^n$? Can you make sure you have not misread or mistyped anything?

Comment: $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+x^n)$$ is the generating series for the [partitions of integers into distinct parts](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at the structures obtained for low values of $n$.

For example,

$(1+x)(1+x^2)=1+x+x^2+x^3$

$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7$.

The resulting expressions can be simplified and understood using the behavior of sums of geometric series.

Comment: Also expressing power as a binary number

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Multuply by $1-x$. Then you get
$$(1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)…(1+x^{2^n})=(1-x^2)(1+x^2)…(1+x^{2^n}) =\\
(1-x^4)(1+x^4)…(1+x^{2^n})=...=(1-x^{2^{n+1}})$$

Thus
$$(1+x)(1+x^2)…(1+x^{2^n})=\frac{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x}$$

Comment: No, we have $(1+x)(1+x^2)\cdots(1+x^{2^n})=\frac{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x}$.

Comment: @user26486 Ty, fixed. That's why i should not type before drinking my coffee :))

Comment: Still, OP says they meant $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\cdots (1+x^{2n})$, in which case none of the answers address the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

An infinite product of terms each approaching one is *not* neccesarly one as well. For instance, see the classic:
$$e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

As to the actual limit, others have beat me to it :)

Comment: The OP's question was if his logic was correct.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that
$$
(1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^{2n})=\frac{(1-x^2)}{1-x}(1+x^2)...(1+x^{2^n})
=\frac{(1-x^4)}{1-x}(1+x^4)...(1+x^{2^n})=\cdots=\frac{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x}\to\frac{1}{1-x}
$$
as $x^{2^{n+1}}\to 0$, whenever $\lvert x\rvert<1$.

Comment: Neat and efficient. Nice thinking!

Comment: @user26486: Indeed. Corrected!

Answer (score 1):

While other answers are based on the product $\prod (1 + x^{2^{n}})$, OP seems to be interested in the product $\prod (1 + x^{n})$. We can do some simplification like the following
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 + x^{n})\notag\\
&= \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1 - x^{2n}}{1 - x^{n}}\notag\\
&= \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1 - x^{2n - 1}}\notag\\
\end{align}

This function has been studied by generations of mathematicians and belongs to the family of ["Theta functions"](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/10/the-magic-of-theta-functions.html) and modern notation is to use $q$ in the place of $x$. Ramanujan studied the function $$g(q) = 2^{-1/4}q^{-1/24}\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{2n - 1}) = \frac{1}{2^{1/4}q^{1/24}f(q)}$$ and made the fundamental discovery that if $r$ is a positive rational number then $g(e^{-\pi\sqrt{r}})$ is a real algebraic number. These numbers are called [Ramanujan's class invariants](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/ramanujans-class-invariants.html) and denoted by $g_{r}$.

Thus for certain values of $q$ of type $q = e^{-\pi\sqrt{r}}, r \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$ the value of $f(q)$ can be evaluated in a closed form in terms of $e, \pi$ and certain algebraic numbers. As an example 
\begin{align}
f(e^{-\pi}) &= (1 + e^{-\pi})(1 + e^{-2\pi})(1 + e^{-3\pi})(1 + e^{-4\pi})\cdots\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{(1 - e^{-\pi})(1 - e^{-3\pi})(1 - e^{-5\pi})\cdots}\notag\\
&= 2^{-1/8}e^{\pi/24}\notag
\end{align}